# Count Array Items in Object of Arrays (combined count)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2017

Consider the following object:

```
const test = {
    foo: ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'],
    bar: ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
    foobar: ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
};
```

How would one go about getting the combined count of all of the items within each of the arrays in the above object?

I am aware that I can do something along the lines of the following:

```
let count = 0;

Object.values(test).forEach(value => count += value.length);

console.log(count) // Expected result: 9
```

I am looking for a simpler (cleaner and hopefully one-liner) way of achieving this...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just get the length of the [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) values.

```js
const test = {
    foo: ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'],
    bar: ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar'],
    foobar: ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']
};

let count = Object.values(test).flat().length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Exactly the sort of thing I am looking for! Thank you!! Will test now

Comment: Works perfectly - will accept as soon as I can. This is exactly why I posted this question. I searched Google for certain keywords but could not find anything. The `flat` method is something I have not come across before... Thank you very much!

Comment: Since the question is tagged ES2017 specifically I'd like to point out that `Array.prototype.flat()` was actually introduced in the ES2019 specification.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - ah, very interesting! I only tagged ES2017 because I wanted to encourage modern solutions. ES2019 is even better :-D

Answer (score 2):

You could use the array reduce, which comes pretty close to a oneliner:

```
const count = Object.values(test).reduce((acc, cv) =>  acc + cv.length ,0)
```

Comment: I like this solution since `reduce()` is the conventional method choice for aggregation and avoids creating a temporary array like `flat()`.